# How to move/slide an image from left to right

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to slide or move a image from left to right something like in

http://rajeevkumarsingh.wix.com/pramtechnology

The read pentagonal box that moves Ok!

I tried a bit but failed to do so.
I used the code as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

<!--
var imgObj = null;
var animate ;
function init(){
   imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
   imgObj.style.position= 'absolute'; 
   imgObj.style.top = '240px';
   imgObj.style.left = '-300px';
   imgObj.style.visibility='hidden';
   moveRight();
} 
function moveRight(){
if (parseInt(imgObj.style.left)<=10)
{
   imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 5 + 'px';
   imgObj.style.visibility='visible';
   animate = setTimeout(moveRight,20); // call moveRight in 20msec
   //stopanimate = setTimeout(moveRight,20);
  }
else
  stop();
  f();
}

function stop(){
   clearTimeout(animate);
}
window.onload =init;
//-->
</script>
<img id="myImage" src="xyz.gif" style="margin-left:170px;" />
```

There some kind of resolution problem with Firefox and IE as well. How to solve them. Also I am not able to move the things so clearly. Is this possible or not? I want it to be with JavaScript and not Flash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var animate, left=0, imgObj=null;

function init(){

   imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
   imgObj.style.position= 'absolute';
   imgObj.style.top = '240px';
   imgObj.style.left = '-300px';
   imgObj.style.visibility='hidden';

   moveRight();
}

function moveRight(){
    left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left, 10);

    if (10 >= left) {
        imgObj.style.left = (left + 5) + 'px';
        imgObj.style.visibility='visible';

        animate = setTimeout(function(){moveRight();},20); // call moveRight in 20msec

        //stopanimate = setTimeout(moveRight,20);
    } else {
        stop();
    }
    //f();
}

function stop(){
   clearTimeout(animate);
}

window.onload = function() {init();};
```

Comment: I fixed it - note the small changes. 1) removed the call to f() which was not defined, 2) put proper { } around your else condition, 3) updated your parseInt() to be done once in moveRight and 4) set the position globally so you're not redefining it repeatedly, 5) wrapped your moveRight setTimeout to be inside a function call and 6) set the image (in html) be inside a relatively positioned container. (Also, my jsFiddle works and yours didn't, so if you see any problem with that, let me know and I'll try to help, but the posted code works as you asked for.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of moving an image to the right as well as fading in from a .js file instead of your index page directly:

----------My index.html page----------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script src="myJava.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    //In pixels
    var amountToMoveTotal = 1000;
    var amountToMovePerStep = 10;
    //In milliseconds
    var timeToWaitBeforeNextIncrement = 20;

    var amountToFadeTotal = 1.0;
    var amountToFadePerStep = 0.01;
</script>

<p>This one moves right on hover</p>
<img onmouseover="moveRight(this, amountToMoveTotal, amountToMovePerStep, timeToWaitBeforeNextIncrement)" src="http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/smiley.gif" style="left:0px;top:50px;position:absolute;opacity:1.0;">
<br><br>
<p>This one fades in on hover</p>
<img onmouseover="fadeIn(this, amountToFadeTotal, amountToFadePerStep, timeToWaitBeforeNextIncrement)" src="http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/smiley.gif" style="left:0px;top:150px;position:absolute;opacity:0.1;">

</body>
</html>
```

----------My myJava.js code----------

```
var animate;
var original = null;

function moveRight(imgObj, amountToMoveTotal, amountToMovePerStep, timeToWaitBeforeNextIncrement)
{
    //Copy original image location
    if (original === null){
        original = parseInt(imgObj.style.left);
    }

    //Check if the image has moved the distance requested
    //If the image has not moved requested distance continue moving.
    if (parseInt(imgObj.style.left) < amountToMoveTotal) {
        imgObj.style.left = (parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + amountToMovePerStep) + 'px';

        animate = setTimeout(function(){moveRight(imgObj, amountToMoveTotal, amountToMovePerStep, timeToWaitBeforeNextIncrement);},timeToWaitBeforeNextIncrement);
    }else {
        imgObj.style.left = original;
        original = null;        
        clearTimeout(animate);
    }
}
function fadeIn(imgObj, amountToFadeTotal, amountToFadePerStep, timeToWaitBeforeNextIncrement)
{
    //Copy original opacity
    if (original === null){
        original = parseFloat(imgObj.style.opacity);
    }

    //Check if the image has faded the amount requested
    //If the image has not faded requested amount continue fading.
    if (parseFloat(imgObj.style.opacity) < amountToFadeTotal) {
        imgObj.style.opacity = (parseFloat(imgObj.style.opacity) + amountToFadePerStep);

        animate = setTimeout(function(){fadeIn(imgObj, amountToFadeTotal, amountToFadePerStep, timeToWaitBeforeNextIncrement);},timeToWaitBeforeNextIncrement);
    }else {
        imgObj.style.opacity = original;
        original = null;
        clearTimeout(animate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery library, is really easy to do what you need

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Follow sample code of page : http://api.jquery.com/stop/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>div { 
position: absolute; 
background-color: #abc;
left: 0px;
top:30px;
width: 60px; 
height: 60px;
margin: 5px; 
}
</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="go">Go</button> 
<button id="stop">STOP!</button>
<button id="back">Back</button>
<div class="block"></div>
<script>
/* Start animation */
$("#go").click(function(){
$(".block").animate({left: '+=100px'}, 2000);
});

/* Stop animation when button is clicked */
$("#stop").click(function(){
$(".block").stop();
});

/* Start animation in the opposite direction */
$("#back").click(function(){
$(".block").animate({left: '-=100px'}, 2000);
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes it is - but it doesn't help him learn. Can we get a jsFiddle of your code?

Comment: and more demos on @flem answer