# How to move divs from left to right then down using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, loops

Hello I have been task to create an image animation that allows the images to move from left to right and then down.

when the images moves down it would have to be overflow hidden as it will go beyond a background image.

The images would be looping continuously, going from left to right and down again. There is a similar example online [how to move/slide an image from left to right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460701/how-to-move-slide-an-image-from-left-to-right).

However, this only slides from left to right and then stop. there is also only one image in animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use css?
Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qkt8veqr/1/)

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position :relative;
    animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}


/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymove{
    0%   {top: 0px; left: 0px;}
    25%  {top: 0px; left: 100px;}
    50%  {top: 0px; left: 0px;}
    75%  {top: 50px; left: 0px;}
    100% {top: 100px; left: 0px;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using CSS animations.  Is it dynamic in any way?  At the end of the keyframe you could simply use overflow: hidden.

Comment: no its just a couple of images flowing over a background image.

Comment: In that case his suggestion is perfect, check out my answer for an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the jQuery function animate() as in this example: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_ani_right

Simply, find the element you want to be moving by jQuery, call animate on him with the right parameter to 0, then after that call animate again with bottom 0 then place the element again on the beginning without animation and this whole loop infinitely.

I am not sure this will work, just a draft:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var element = $("something");
  while (true) {
    element.animate({right:"0"});
    element.animate({bottom:"0"});
    element.css("right", "auto").css("bottom", "auto").css("left", "0").css("top", "0");
  }
});
```