# animate image from left to right then down

Tags: javascript

Trying to get this to move across screen from left to right then down, I currently have this working to move the picture into the correct position ona button click, but it is not animated

```
function myMove()
{
 var himg = document.getElementById( parameter.pictureID );

 himg.style.left = (himg.style.left +1700) +"px";
 himg.style.top = (himg.style.top+ 700) +"px";
     setTimeout(myMove,20); // call doMove() in 20 msec
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in thread [how to move/slide an image from left to right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460701/how-to-move-slide-an-image-from-left-to-right) *setTimeout* is called by

```
 var animate;
 animate = setTimeout(function(){moveRight();},20);
```

the move function is named moveRight()

there is also a jquery library

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

see the thread [how to move/slide an image from left to right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460701/how-to-move-slide-an-image-from-left-to-right)

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this with CSS3 transition;

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

put transition: left 10s, top 10s; on the element you're moving, you can also benefit here from other transition capabilities